# Why does the testing condition has no effect

Tags: c++

This program is supposed to stop when the user presses Y or y, but my testing testing condition has no effect on the code, the program keeps on asking the user for the next number.

```html
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

int prime(int);

void main(void)
{
    int n;
    char ch='i';

mylabel:
    cout << "\nEnter num: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << prime(n);
    cout << "\nPress N or n to exit : ";
    if (getche() != ('N' || 'n')) {
        goto mylabel;
    }
    cout << ",,,";
}

int prime(int p)
{
    int test = 1;
    if( (p>2 && p%2==0) || p==0 || p==1 || p<0)
        return 0;
    for (int i=3 ; i<=(int(sqrt(p)))+1 ;i+=2)
    {
      if(p%i==0)
      test=0;
      break;
    }
    return test;
}
```

Comment: Because it's a silly question that's not going to help anyone in the future. Where did you read that `if (getche() != ('N' || 'n'))` is the right way to combine conditions? Not your C++ book, certainly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What is the right way?

Comment: Probably better to start with a language that's friendlier to beginners than C++.  And get a good book too, or actually turn up to lectures and read your course material :p.

Comment: Furthermore, `main` always must return `int` and `iostream.h` hasn't existed for almost 20 years. I'm getting a little tired of having to say this on 80% of new Stack Overflow C++ questions. Does nobody read the existing material any more???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are taking sloppy English and translating it literally to create broken C++.

When you say:

```
the character is not 'N' or 'n'
```

this, while commonplace, is *wrong*. For the same reason, your C++ code is *wrong*. You are comparing `getche()` to `'N' || 'n'`, an expression which applies boolean-OR to two `char`s, always resulting in `true`.

You mean to say either of:

```
the character is neither 'N' nor 'n'
the character is not 'N' and the character is not 'n'
```

C++ only has an equivalent for the latter construct, and here it is:

```
if (getche() != 'N' && getche() != 'n')
```

Of course, you only want to read *one* character, so:

```
const char c = getche();
if (c != 'N' && c != 'n')
```

Comment: @HashirOmer: I don't know what you expect me to do with the sheer wealth of information in your latest feedback.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Press 4 for payment options.

Comment: @Illaz: Not seeing any incoming payments.